# PyQt- Which column received the right-click?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a horizontal header and I'm setting it up to catch right clicks like so:

```
self.horizontalHeader.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.horizontalHeader.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.callFilter)
```

I'd like to know which column of the header the right-click landed on. I can get the positions through `self.horizontalHeader.viewport()` but I'm stuck there. Translating the position from the header to the position in the header's table seems inelegant. Is there a better way to capture the right click, or a better way for find where it landed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`logicalindexAt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#logicalIndexAt-3) will return column number, in case it's horizontal header:

```
def callFilter(self, pos):
    column = self.horizontalHeader.logicalIndexAt(pos)
```